# covariance matrix is not positive definite

Tags: matrices, covariance

I have a feature vector(FV1) of size 1*n. Now I subtract mean of all feature vectors from the feature vector FV1 Now I take transpose of that(FV1_Transpose) which is n*1. Now I add do matrix multiplication (FV1_Transpose * FV1) to get covariance matrix which is n*n.

But my problem is that I dont get a positive definite matrix. I read everywhere that covariance matrix should be symmetric positive definite.

FV1 after subtraction of mean = -17.7926788,0.814089298,33.8878059,-17.8336430,22.4685001;

Covariance matrix = 
316.579407, -14.4848289, -602.954834, 317.308289, -399.774811;
-14.4848289, 0.662741363, 27.5876999, -14.5181780, 18.2913647;
-602.954834, 27.5876999, 1148.38342, -604.343018, 761.408142;
317.308289, -14.5181780, -604.343018, 318.038818, -400.695221;
-399.774811, 18.2913647, 761.408142, -400.695221, 504.833496;

This covariance matrix is not positive definite. Any ideawhy is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The matrix is positive **semi**-definite of rank 1. Eigen-solvers can compute some spurious small negative eigenvalues due to roundoff.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you for your reply. Is there any option to avoid this round off?

Comment: What do you want to do with this matrix? If you need to compute its eigenvalues they are simply $n-1$ zeros and the value of `FV1 * FV1_transpose`.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel thanks a lot for your reply. My actual scenario is more complex. I do LDA(Linear Discriminant analysis). For that I construct Between class scatter matrix and Within class scatter matrix inverse. When I find Within class scatter matrix inverse, I get "1.#INF0000" and "-1.#INF0000". I need to find a solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what is true is that the covariance matrix should be positive **semidefinite**.  It can have eigenvalues of $0$ corresponding to hyperplanes that all the data lie in.

Now if you have a matrix that is positive semidefinite but not positive definite, but your computation is numerical and thus incurs some roundoff error, you may end up with a matrix that has some small negative eigenvalues.  That is presumably what has happened here, where two of the eigenvalues are approximately
-0.0000159575212286663 and -0.0000136360857634093.  These, as well as the next two very small positive eigenvalues, should probably be 0.  Your matrix is very close to the rank-1 matrix  u^T u, where 
u = [-17.7927, .814089,  33.8878, -17.8336, 22.4685 ].  Thus your data points should all be very close to a line in this direction.